# Evaluate a Perl String to zero for numbers only

Tags: perl

I have a situation where I expect variables to be passed to me as strings or numbers.

i.e.

```
sub foo {
    # These can be either strings or numbers
    my ($bar, $var, $star) = @_;

    # I need to check to see if $bar is the number 0 (zero)
    if ($bar == 0) {
        # Do super magic with it
    }
}
```

Unfortunately Perl tries to do the super magic on `$bar` when it contains a string.

How can I tell Perl to do super magic on `$bar` if and only if it is the **number** 0 (zero)?

I understand Perl fundamentally interprets based on context, which is the underlying problem here.  A possible solution to this problem is to use regex, which is fine, but I wanted to know if there was another more "straight-forward" solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) can you give examples of things that match using super-magic? 2) could you use the string-equality operator 'eq' instead? This will catch where $bar is equal to '0' and will ignore  but not other forms like '0.0' or '00'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd personally go with what @Disco3's comment said.

```
if ($bar eq 0) { ... }
```

This works for `$bar = 0`, `$bar = 'foo'` and `$bar = 123` giving the expected result.

Here's a fun fact, though:

```
use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);
my $bar = '0';

cmpthese(-1, {
  'quoted'    => sub { $bar eq '0'    },
  'unquoted'  => sub { $bar eq 0      },
  'regex'     => sub { $bar =~ m/^0$/ },
});
```

Benchmarking these three solutions tells us that the unquoted `0` is the fastest way to do it.

```
               Rate    regex   quoted unquoted
regex     4504851/s       --     -70%     -76%
quoted   15199885/s     237%       --     -19%
unquoted 18828298/s     318%      24%       --
```

Comment: But with the slowest taking less than a quarter of a microsecond, who cares? The clearest solution should *always* be chosen first.

Comment: I agree, that's why I said it was a fun fact. ;) I do think the `eq` is clearer than the regex, but that is my personal opinion. I believe everyone has to decide that for themselves, or do as the coding guidelines tell them.

Comment: What it doesn't work with is `0.0`, and I for one would be thrown by what this code meant.

Comment: @darch: That is right, but the OP said he wanted it to work *if and only if it is the number 0 (zero)*. I don't think that includes `0.0`.

Comment: simbabque is correct.  I know what **if and only if** means.  :) I expect a single character 0 (zero) from a parse.  I ended up using the `eq` solution given here - it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Why not:

```
if ( $bar =~ m/^0$/ ) {
```

Comment: I know this will work, but I was wondering if there was a solution that didn't involve regex.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "number 0". Obviously, you include the one character string `0` is zero. But what you about three character string `0.0`?

If you just want to match the one character string `0`, use

```
if ($bar eq '0') {
   ...
}
```

If you want to match what Perl considers number zero, use

```
use Scalar::Util qw( looks_like_number );

if (looks_like_number($bar) && $bar == 0) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Between `looks_like_number` and numerical comparisons, you can get quite good results quite easily:

```
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);
use Test::More tests => 7;

sub is_numerically_zero {
    my ($string) = @_;

    return (looks_like_number($string) and $string == 0);
}

for my $string (qw(0 0.0 0e0), '  0  ') {
    ok(is_numerically_zero($string));
}

for my $string (qw(duckies 123), '') {
    ok(not is_numerically_zero($string));
}
```

This assumes you don't want to just match the literal string `'0'`.